# Javascript 2-d associative arrays

Tags: javascript, jsp, associative-array

I have a Javascript 2-D array defined as follows:

```
proData[prov_999998] = new Array();

proData[prov_999998]["address"] = "29 South St. South #202  Uxbridge   ON  L9P 1V9";

proData[prov_999998]["phone"] = "555-555-5555";

proData[prov_999998]["fax"] = "444-444-4444";
```

I'm trying to access these array elements in this function:

```
function switchPro(value) {
document.getElementById("letterheadName").value = value;
document.getElementById("letterheadAddress").value = providerData[prov_999998]["address"];
document.getElementById("letterheadAddressSpan").innerHTML = providerData[prov_999998]["address"] ;  
document.getElementById("letterheadPhone").value = providerData[prov_999998]["phone"];
document.getElementById("letterheadPhoneSpan").innerHTML = providerData[prov_999998]["phone"]; 
document.getElementById("letterheadFax").value = providerData[prov_999998]["fax"]; 
document.getElementById("letterheadFaxSpan").innerHTML = providerData[prov_999998]["fax"]; 
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying: "prov_999998 is undefined in "providerData[prov_999998]["address"];". 
Can someone please help me with this? I can't have numbers as array indexes because javascript does not accept array index starting with '0' such as [0999]. These array indexes are Ids entered by the user and I can't put a restriction on the Id format. I am new to javascript so I'd appreciate any help.

Actually, I want the 1st index to be a variable. This is what I was doing:

```
function switchProvider(value) {
    var val =  "prov_"+value; 
    document.getElementById("letterheadName").value = value;
    document.getElementById("letterheadAddress").value = providerData[val]["address"];
    document.getElementById("letterheadAddressSpan").innerHTML = providerData[val]["address"] ; 
    document.getElementById("letterheadPhone").value = providerData[val]["phone"];
    document.getElementById("letterheadPhoneSpan").innerHTML = providerData[val]["phone"]; 
    document.getElementById("letterheadFax").value = providerData[val]["fax"]; 
    document.getElementById("letterheadFaxSpan").innerHTML = providerData[val]["fax"]; 

    }
```

But this is not working, the values on the webpage are being rendered as 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Here's more code, it's JSP and Javascript together.

```
var providerData = new Array();
<% 
for (Provider p : prList) {
if (!p.getProviderNo().equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
        String prov_no = "prov_"+p.getProviderNo();
        %>
    providerData[<%=prov_no%>]["address"] = "<%=(p.getClinicAddress() + "  " + p.getClinicCity() + "   " + p.getClinicProvince() + "  " + p.getClinicPostal()).trim() %>";
    providerData[<%=prov_no%>]["phone"] = "<%=p.getClinicPhone().trim() %>";
    providerData[<%=prov_no%>]["fax"] = "<%=p.getClinicFax().trim() %>";

<%  } 
} %>
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Is `proData` a global variable? Why did you switch to `providerData` later? Additionally, in switchPro(value) you should (for your own experimentation) do `for ( key in providerData[prov_999998]) console.log(key)` and similarly `for (key in providerData) console.log(key)`

Comment: Thanks for including more code, that clears some things up. Did you intend to go from proData to providerData? Is proData or providerData a global variable?

Comment: providerData is a global variable, I just changed the name from provData...Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: for your own enlightenment, in switchProvider include the following line before `var val='prov_'+value;` ... (include this: ) `for (key in providerData) console.log(key);` and ensure that `'prov_'+value` is included in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you use is for object key/value pairs, and not for arrays.

You should most likely use

```
var proData = {};

proData['prov_999998'] = {};
proData['prov_999998']["address"] = "29 South St. South #202  Uxbridge   ON  L9P 1V9";
proData['prov_999998']["phone"] = "555-555-5555";
proData['prov_999998']["fax"] = "444-444-4444";
```

and access it with (*i.e.*)

```
providerData['prov_999998']["address"];
```

Now if prov_999998 is a variable then you should indeed access it without the quotes i added, but make sure that it has a value assigned, and that this value still persists when you try to use it in your function ..

---

original answer

<strike>You should wrap the prov_999998 in quotes `'prov_999998'` to make it a literal, otherwise it is treated as a variable.</strike>

```
proData['prov_999998'] = new Array();
proData['prov_999998']["address"] = "29 South St. South #202  Uxbridge   ON  L9P 1V9";
proData['prov_999998']["phone"] = "555-555-5555";
proData['prov_999998']["fax"] = "444-444-4444";
```

and

```
function switchPro(value) {
  document.getElementById("letterheadName").value = value;
  document.getElementById("letterheadAddress").value = providerData['prov_999998']["address"];
  document.getElementById("letterheadAddressSpan").innerHTML = providerData['prov_999998']["address"] ;  
  document.getElementById("letterheadPhone").value = providerData['prov_999998']["phone"];
  document.getElementById("letterheadPhoneSpan").innerHTML = providerData['prov_999998']["phone"]; 
  document.getElementById("letterheadFax").value = providerData['prov_999998']["fax"]; 
  document.getElementById("letterheadFaxSpan").innerHTML = providerData['prov_999998']["fax"]; 
}
```

Comment: Those are not `Array`s. Initialise rather with `proData['prov_999998'] = { address: '...', phone: '...', fax: '...' }

Comment: if `var prov_999998 = 'value'` is called then this works fine. I imagine that's what's occurring.

Comment: Actually, I want it to be a variable. This is what I was doing:

Comment: @drachenstern, it works by assigning new properties to the array object. Not really using the array as one..

Comment: @Sapphire, the code i posted (*using objects `{}` instead of arrays*) will work just fine. You can use a variable instead but you must ensure that it contains a string and not a number so that it does not lose the leading 0s.

Comment: @Gaby aka G.Petrioli - it's still giving me an error  providerData.prov_999998 is undefined
[Break On This Error] document.getElementById("letterheadAd...oviderData['prov_999998']["address"];

Answer (score 0):

The fact there are enough indexes to get to 999998 in a Javascript memory structure is worrisome. You're definitely going to knock a browser over if much of the preceding entries are loaded alongside it.

Is there anything wrong with calling the index 999 instead of 0999?

It looks like you're trying to use strings to index the secondary items in the array, rather than indexes - like 'address' and 'phone'.

So, your structure should be hashmaps of hashmaps:

```
var providerData = {
    '0999': {
        address: '321 Sesame St',
        zip: '12345'
    },
    '1000': {// more here
    }
};

alert(providerData['0999']['address']); // alerts "321 Sesame St"
```

But you should consider the amount of data loaded into it.

Comment: Nah, for something with 3 * 1,000,000 elements, modern browsers can handle that with no sweat. ~ I agree IE8 or FX2 would've choked, but IE9, Chrome, FX4, those can handle 3 million elements in an array with relative ease. What's worrisome is that the structure seems incredibly fragile.

Comment: That depends on the size of the 3 million structures stored in those elements, and how much processing is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your associative array is wrong (or your code lacks info).

```
proData[prov_999998] = new Array();
```

should be

```
proData['prov_999998'] = new Array();
```

and so on. Anyhow, you could use javascript objects to do that in a neat way.

Comment: Why must it be so? why can't `var prov_999998 = '1'` be used?